# How to access GCP VM memory/storage from other device/web app?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a backend server on gcp that precomputes some data and saves it to its storage a file and react app from which I want to fetch this data.

Is there any way how to access this file directly? Sth like

```
fetch("https://IP_address/file")
```

Or what is an optimal way to get this data to the app?

Comment: Depending on the OS, use SSH to access the remote system. Other options include deploying a web server, a small Flask app, etc. Be careful to think about security.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a (perfect) VM as a bunker: you can't enter without authorization and you can't get what there are in.

If you need access to this bunker, you need to add doors: HTTPS (webserver), FTP (port 21), SFTP (port 22), SSH (port 22), SCP (port 22),...

Choose your preferred door with the most convenient access and security level. For react web app access, HTTPS webserver is the preferred way. however, you can also serve file in HTTP if you store them in Cloud Storage.